# API to get WiFi channel in Widows 8/10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wifi

I'm looking for a WinAPI function to extract the WiFi channel of the current AP that my computer is connected to, such as the channel noted in the output below (11). I can do it via 'netsh' command line, and I can obviously write a program that executes this command and parses the output, but I was hoping to find a cleaner, more direct way.

```
C:\Users\>netsh wlan show interfaces
There is 1 interface on the system:
Name                   : Wireless Network Connection
Description            : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
GUID                   : 
Physical address       : 
State                  : connected
SSID                   : 
BSSID                  : 
Network type           : Infrastructure
Radio type             : 802.11g
Authentication         : 
Cipher                 : 
Connection mode        : 
***Channel***          : 11
Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 54
Signal                 : 99%
Profile                : 
Hosted network status  : Not started
```

Programming language is C/C++.

Comment: You don't specify a language. C, C++, Delphi, C#, VB.net, Go, Erlang, `><>`?

Comment: C/C++. Sorry. edited.

Comment: No problem, There's also no need to put in the `edit` note at this point. I also edited the tags to help the searchability.

Comment: Have you looked at [`WlanQueryInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765(v=vs.85).aspx)?  It looks appropriate and has a sample which looks like it would meet your needs.  See also: [Native Wifi API Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa816369(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Alternatively `WlanEnumInterfaces` followed by `WlanGetNetworkBssList`.